# How to pass levels of a factor as arguments in a function using Purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a function that takes individual levels of a factor as an argument. I would like to be able to take a factor, find all levels of it, and then pass these to the function in one step.

It sounds like something easy to achieve using `purrr` but I can't get my head around where the mapping goes and how it works.

In the example below I can get to the desired output (a dataframe) via several intermediary steps (e.g. passing each level of the factor one at a time), how can I use `purrr` to do this in one step? Many thanks.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# create example function
my_iris_data <- function(data, species){
  data %>%
    filter(Species == species) %>% 
    mutate(my_measure = Petal.Length / Petal.Width)
}

# find all levels of factor
levs <- levels(iris$Species)

# plug each level into our function, one at a time
df1 <- my_iris_data(data = iris, species = levs[1])
df2 <- my_iris_data(data = iris, species = levs[2])
df3 <- my_iris_data(data = iris, species = levs[3])

# bind all intermediary steps together
desired_output_df <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)
```

Comment: I am not really clear on what you are trying to achieve. In your example code `
iris %>% mutate(my_measure = Petal.Length / Petal.Width)` would give you the same result. Please reword the question stating the actual function you mention in the first sentence of your post.

Comment: The two downvotes suggest others might also have found the question unclear, sorry. The question is really intended to be about the use of purrr with functions generally rather than with any one specific function. The function provided in the example is purely for illustration.

Comment: What is unclear is that `my_iris_data` takes two arguments, a data frame and a level. But you want to work with a function that takes only levels?

Comment: I don't think the question is unclear or deserves downvotes. You have shared 1) a reproducible example 2) Desired output 3) What you have tried. This is already better than 90% of questions posted on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map_df`

```
desired_output_df1 <- purrr::map_df(levs, my_iris_data, data = iris)
identical(desired_output_df, desired_output_df1)
#[1] TRUE
```

which is similar to `lapply` + `do.call` `rbind` in base R :

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(levs, my_iris_data, data = iris))
```